# Count with conditions of a 2nd list

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

XML I: (e.g. shopping-cart, image-gallery)

```
<list1>
    <entry>
        ...
        <items>
            <item id="1"></item>
            <item id="2"></item>
            <item id="3"></item>
        </items>
    </entry>
</list1>
```

XML II: (=associated items)

```
<list2>
    <entry id="1">
        ...
        <visibility>
            <item value="public">Public</item>
        </visibility>
    </entry>
    <entry id="3">
        ...
        <visibility>
            <item value="private">Private</item>
        </visibility>
    </entry>
    <entry id="5">
        ...
        <visibility>
            <item value="public">Public</item>
        </visibility>
    </entry>
</list2>
```

Notice: The ID's in list2 might match or not...

How to get the count of items of list1 which have an ID in list2 and /visibility/item/@value = 'public' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 you can use `count(/list1/entry/item[@id = document('xml2.xml')/list2/entry[visibility/item/@value = 'public']/@id])`.

With XSLT 2.0 a key

```
<xsl:template name="k1" match="list2/entry[visibility/item/@value = 'public']" use="@id"/>
```

and then

```
count(/list1/entry/item[key('k1', @id, document('xml2.xml'))])
```

makes the lookup more efficient.